401 Unauthorized and req.user Undefined After Deployment (Local Works Fine)
0
I have a MEVN app using Passport.js for authentication. Everything works fine when both the server and client are running locally. However, after deploying one or both the server (on Back4App) and the client (on Vercel), I encounter a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to access the cart API, which requires the user to be logged in. Upon investigating, I found that req.user is undefined in the deployed environment, unlike when running locally. I've tried applying various community solutions, but the issue persists. What could be causing this, and how can I resolve it?
Below was my backend code, server.mjs file:
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";

import passport from "passport";
import LocalStrategy from "passport-local";
import User from "./models/userModel.js";

import AuthRoute from "./routes/authRoute.js";
import CartRoute from "./routes/cartRoute.js";
import CategoryRoute from "./routes/categoryRoute.js";
import TransactionRoute from "./routes/transactionRoute.js";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

// Mengaktifkan trust proxy
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

// connect to database
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
  });

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["https://digitronix.vercel.app", "http://localhost:5173"],
  })
);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    // store: MongoStore.create({
    //   mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
    //   collectionName: "sessions",
    //   autoRemove: "interval",
    //   autoRemoveInterval: 1320,
    // }),
    cookie: {
      // domain: ".localhost",
      secure: 'auto',
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
  })
);

// passport middleware
// app.use(passport.authenticate('session'))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
//   console.log("Serialized User:", user._id);
//   done(null, user._id);
// });

// passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
//   try {
//     const user = await User.findById(id);
//     console.log("Deserialized User:", user);
//     done(null, user);
//   } catch (err) {
//     done(err, null);
//   }
// });

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Session:", req.session);
  console.log("User:", req.user);
  next();
});

// routes
app.use("/", AuthRoute);
app.use("/cart", CartRoute);
app.use("/categories", CategoryRoute);
app.use("/transactions", TransactionRoute);

app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server running on port http://localhost:${process.env.APP_PORT}`
  );
});

cartController.js
import Cart from "../models/cartModel.js";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";

export const index = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "You must login first" });
    }
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).populate("carts");
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User not found");
    res.status(200).json(user.carts);
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Error retrieving carts: " + error.message });
  }
};

export const store = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const newCart = new Cart(req.body);
    await newCart.save();

    user.carts.push(newCart);
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json(newCart);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json("Error saving: " + error.message);
  }
};

export const update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { quantity } = req.body;
    const { item_id } = req.params;

    const cartItem = await Cart.findById(item_id);
    if (!cartItem) return res.status(404).send("Item not found");

    cartItem.quantity = quantity;
    await cartItem.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Item saved successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(404)
      .json({ message: "Error updating quantity: " + error.message });
  }
};

export const destroy = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "You must login first" });
    }

    const { item_id } = req.params;
    if (!item_id) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Item ID is required" });
    }

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User not found");

    // Ensure the user has the item in their cart
    if (!user.carts.includes(item_id)) {
      return res.status(404).send("Item not found in user's cart");
    }

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { $pull: { carts: item_id } });
    await Cart.findByIdAndDelete(item_id);

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Cart deleted successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json("Error deleting: " + error.message);
  }
};

export const destroyAll = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "You must login first" });
    }

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).populate('carts');
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User not found");

    // Clear all cart the user has
    await Cart.deleteMany({_id: { $in: user.carts}});

    // Delete all cart id in the cars array
    user.carts = [];
    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Carts deleted successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json("Error deleting: " + error.message);
  }
}

isAuthenticated middleware
export const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Session:", req.session);
    console.log("User:", req.user);
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "You're unauthorized" });
    }
    next();
  }

cartRoute.js
import express from 'express';
import {index, store, update, destroy, destroyAll} from "../controllers/cartController.js";
import { validateCart } from '../middlewares/validator.js';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../middlewares/isAuthenticated.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', isAuthenticated, index);
router.post('/', isAuthenticated, validateCart, store);
router.put('/:item_id', isAuthenticated, update);
router.delete('/:item_id', isAuthenticated, destroy);
router.delete('/', isAuthenticated, destroyAll);

export default router;

And this was my frontend code that fetch cart api using axios, cartService.js file:
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BACKEND_URL}/cart`

export const getCartItems = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(API_URL, { withCredentials: true })
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || 'Error getting cart data')
  }
}

export const addToCart = async (newItem) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, newItem, { withCredentials: true })
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || 'Error add new cart')
  }
}

export const updateCartItem = async (item_id, quantity) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.put(
      `${API_URL}/${item_id}`,
      { quantity },
      { withCredentials: true }
    )
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || 'Error update new quantity')
  }
}

export const deleteCartItem = async (item_id) => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`${API_URL}/${item_id}`, { withCredentials: true })
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || 'Error delete cart item')
  }
}

export const clearCart = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(API_URL, { withCredentials: true })
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || 'Error clear cart')
  }
}

export default {
  getCartItems,
  addToCart,
  updateCartItem,
  deleteCartItem,
  clearCart
}

I tried deploying my MEVN app with the server on Back4App and the client on Vercel. I expected the user authentication to work the same way as it did locally, where the req.user is defined after login, allowing access to protected routes like the cart API. However, after deployment, req.user becomes undefined, and I get a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to access these routes. I expected the user session to persist properly across server and client after deployment, just like in local development.
